# Heroku deploy stopped working

Tags: git, heroku

I have a python heroku app with 2 dynos (one web and one worker).
Since the last couple of hours I can't seem to deploy

When trying to deploy ("git push heroku master") I get the following error

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

This used to work fine until today.

I also checked for the following and they seem to be correct:

- My public key is defined under my account
- My app is responding (e.g. not idle)
- The repository url is correctly configured in the git config file

What else could have changed?

Comment: i dont know anything about heroku but this does seem to be a GIT problem and not a heroku problem.

Comment: Can you first see if the repository's server is reachable i.e. something like `ping whatever-heroku-server.com`. Next try running a `git fetch heroku` to fetch from the remote name `heroku`. If this command succeeds at least the repository is reachable and readable. You might still have permissions issues when pushing into the repo though.

Comment: Should have mentioned that the repository is hosted on github. Anyway I assume it's reachable. when running `git fetch heroku` I get the same error. I am not sure what you mean by permissions issues - afaik the only thing needed is to add my ssh-key in my heroku account.

Comment: It then sounds like the public key being provided by your local machine is not a valid one on the github account. I presume you've already gone over these steps: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys ? Try the last command mentioned on the page to verify you're able to talk to the server: `ssh -T git@github.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find the issue.

When running `ssh -vT git@github.com` (Thanks for the pointer @Tuxdude) I noticed it was looking for my ssh identity under `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Apparently my ssh key files were named `github_rsa` and `github_rsa.pub`.

Changing the names to `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` solved the issue.

Still not sure how it worked before as I always had the files named like that.

Comment: Nice catch! For future reference, you can also explicitly specify which key you are wanting to add. For instance, you could use `heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/github_rsa.pub` if that's the one you wanted to use.

Comment: Same for me - I could push fine then this problem appeared out of nowhere, (The only thing I can think of was I went 9 days(!) without pushing to Heroku, and Heroku closed/resolved an unrelated support ticket I had open).  I don't know what went wrong, but renaming my keys worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following commnands:

```
$ heroku keys:clear
$ heroku keys:add
```

The first one will remove any expectations that Heroku has for any keys you have. The second will add your key back to your heroku account. If you have further issues, try the following first, then the aforementioned commands next:

```
$ heroku auth:logout
$ heroku auth:login
```

That will ensure that you are properly authorized to the correct account.